# Set DigitalOcean server timezone not working

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I live in Nairobi, Kenya. My website's time works well on my local WAMP server, I have this as my PHP time function.

```php
// prettify time date
function soshDate($date) {
    // timezone
    date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Nairobi");
    // current time
    $now = time();
    $old = strtotime($date);
    $diff =  $now-$old;
    $old = new DateTime($date);
    // check time passed
    if ($diff /60 <= 1) { return " 1 sec"; }
    else if (intval($diff/60) == 1) { return " 1 min"; }
    else if ($diff / 60 < 60){ return intval($diff/60)." mins"; }
    else if (intval($diff / 3600) == 1){ return " 1 hr"; }
    else if ($diff / 3600 <24){ return intval($diff/3600) . " hrs"; }
    else if ($diff/86400  == 1 ){ return "yesterday"; }
    else if ($diff/86400  > 1 && $diff/86400 <= 7){ return$old->format('D'); }
    else if ($diff/86400 > 7 && $diff/86400 <= 31){ return$old->format('j M'); }
    else{ return $old->format('j M');  }
}
```

However, even after using this `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Nairobi` to set my digitalocean timezone as well as getting the correct time when I run `$ date` on the CLI, the time I get when I run the function `soshDate($date)` of which the date's format is `2022-05-30 15:00:06` . I still get a date that is 3hrs behind my local time. I need help correcting this.

Comment: I'd start by replacing all that math you are doing there, with a proper use of `DateTime::diff` to begin with.

Comment: my research is showing an NTP service issue

Answer (score 1):

A work around I am using is `$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. ' + 3 hours'))` in my soshDate function